# reset snap configuration

Tags: snap

Is there a way to reset a snap configuration back to what it was when first installed?

For instance, I could do

```
snap remove --purge intellij-idea-educational
```

But then I need to install it again, including the large download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded snaps are stored in `/var/lib/snapd/cache/`.

Removing a snap will not remove files in this folder, even if you use the `--purge`-option.

Unless you removed the corresponding file(s) manually or a new version of the snap is available you can install the snap again without the need to download it again.

Comment: I see, it must have updated. Then Im forced to update